# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol cvCreateImage referenced in function main

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, lnk2019, unresolved-external

I tried to build a code snippet in my MS VS Codes 2022 community version. I configured all the needed things to use the functionalities in OpenCV. But, I'm getting a set of errors.
The configurations I have done are mentioned below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
Error:

```
Error   LNK1120 7 unresolved externals  Project1    D:\L4S1\DIP\Labs\Lab2\Project1\x64\Debug\Project1.exe   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol cvWaitKey referenced in function main    Project1    D:\L4S1\DIP\Labs\Lab2\Project1\Project1\Lab1.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol cvDestroyWindow referenced in function main  Project1    D:\L4S1\DIP\Labs\Lab2\Project1\Project1\Lab1.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol cvShowImage referenced in function main  Project1    D:\L4S1\DIP\Labs\Lab2\Project1\Project1\Lab1.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol cvNamedWindow referenced in function main    Project1    D:\L4S1\DIP\Labs\Lab2\Project1\Project1\Lab1.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol cvLoadImage referenced in function main  Project1    D:\L4S1\DIP\Labs\Lab2\Project1\Project1\Lab1.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol cvReleaseImage referenced in function main   Project1    D:\L4S1\DIP\Labs\Lab2\Project1\Project1\Lab1.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol cvCreateImage referenced in function main    Project1    D:\L4S1\DIP\Labs\Lab2\Project1\Project1\Lab1.obj    1
```

Comment: is this C or C++? [mre] please. -- those are functions that only existed in OpenCV v1 and were already deprecated in OpenCV v2, _certainly_ in v3. talk to the supervisor of your lab.

Comment: C++,I'll add an example of code to the above question

Comment: In your third picture you have a `.lib` file listed as the folder that contains the libraries. I know a folder could have that name but its odd. You probably need the absolute path of the opencv libs folder instead.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I sorted out the problem and published the answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing the configurations under Linker I have done a mistake. When the configuration is in Debug status, need to add the opencv_world3413d.lib under the input field. In my above-posted question, I have put it under General in the Linker section. The corrected configuration should be as below,

[image]